# Check if values exist in 2 tables within a specific time frame?

Tags: sql, database

I need to somehow get a list of patients that have an [appointment date] in both of these tables in any combination. (for example, can appear in Table A twice, or table A and B, or Table B twice) all since the first of November 2015 - present day.

Really struggling with this one so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Patient Table A** 
PatientID, appointment date, test, blah, blah

**Patient Table B** 
PatientID, appointment date, blah blah

I think what I'd prefer is to have all rows returned from both tables if possible? Ideal output would look something like

```
PatientID, Appointment Date, Age, Gender, Location 
86677, 23-11-2015, Age 74, Male, UK
86677, 03-12-2015, Age 74, Male, UK
```

Also, if Table A is Outpatients and Table B is Inpatients, how would I add an extra column to help identify? For example, if the above example had an Inpatient appointment on 23-11-2015 and an outpatient one on 03-12-2015, how could I identify the 2 in my output?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why do you have two very similar tables?

Comment: They are 2 similar tables as one is outpatients and one is inpatients.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably end up being quite slow, but the basic logic is:

```
  SELECT patient_id 
    FROM (       
      SELECT patient_id
        FROM table_a
       WHERE appointment_date >= '2015-11-01'       
   UNION ALL
      SELECT patient_id
        FROM table_b
       WHERE appointment_date >= '2015-11-01'
         ) combined
GROUP BY patient_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

You may get better performance from breaking up the combinations:

```
  SELECT patient_id
    FROM table_a
   WHERE appointment_date >= '2015-11-01'
GROUP BY patient_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 
   UNION 
  SELECT patient_id
    FROM table_b
   WHERE appointment_date >= '2015-11-01'
GROUP BY patient_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 
   UNION
  SELECT a.publisher_id
    FROM table_a a
    JOIN table_b b
      ON b.patient_id = a.patient_id 
     AND b.appointment_date >= '2015-11-01'
   WHERE a.appointment_date >= '2015-11-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is designed with SQL server in mind, although it would work with a few other dialects. The basic idea is to combine your two tables with a new attribute (inpatient/outpatient) into a virtual table that you can call in the following query. This is known as a Common Table Expression (CTE).

The CTE creates a combo table that you can then perform some checks on. We perform the date check in the CTE, but after we've combined the tables in order to avoid repeating the date filter. When we call the CTE, we get it to return a list of PatientIDs for patients who have 2 or more records in the combo table. We use that list as a filter in the WHERE to select all the records for those patients from that same list.

```
WITH combo AS
( SELECT
    *
  FROM
    ( SELECT
          PatientID
        , Appointment_Date
        , Age
        , Gender
        , Location
        , 'Inpatient'  Record_Source
      FROM
        TableB

      UNION ALL /* UNION drops duplicates; need UNION ALL */

      SELECT
          PatientID
        , Appointment_Date
        , Age
        , Gender
        , Location
        , 'Outpatient'  Record_Source
      FROM
        TableB
    ) sub
  WHERE  /* Filter date after union to be DRY programming */
    Appointment_Date >= '2015-11-01'
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  combo
WHERE
  PatientID IN
    ( SELECT PatientID
      FROM combo
      GROUP BY PatientID
      HAVING count(*) >= 2
    )
```